Any official (Google's) resources for finding basic Android terms definitions?
Is there any official resource(s) to find definitions of the following terms:

Android,
Android Open Source Project (AOSP) (and how it's different from just Android? Because according to "source.android.com", "Android is an open source operating system [1] for mobile devices and a corresponding open source project led by Google." [1] Also, if Android is an open source OS, what do you call an official Android OS from Google that contains non-open source elements to it? Also Android?..),
Android platform (what kind of platform is it? Is it a software-only platform, or hardware platform as well?.. The only thing I found under the "What is Android" section at "android.com/what-is-android" is "The platform changing what mobile can do." (The link also doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere on the "android.com" website.)).

as well as of other basic terms like these? (Please no secondary sources.)

The only official source for reliable information on Androi is android.com. To gain a deeper understanding of specific terms, it’s helpful to explore multiple sources.
Coming to your question about AOSP, it is the most barebone, most basic version of Android as built by the Android development team at Google. Depending on the Android phone's manufacturer, they modify the AOSP rom as per their requirements, and this is called as the Stock ROM. You can refer to this document here for more information on this.
Jayanta's answer explores this more as well.


Any official (Google's) resources for finding basic Android terms definitions?

No. You can have my takes if you want:
Android:
Name for the OS itself (like "MacOS" or "Windows")
Android Open Source Project (AOSP):
The repository containing the source code from which the core Android Operation System is built.
What's the difference:
"Android" is a catchall term that usually refers to the OS but can be contextual. Sometimes it's an OS ("runs on Android"). Sometimes it's source code ("Android is open source"). Sometimes it's a phone ("I have an Android").
An official Android OS from Google that contains non-open source elements to it:
A build or version of Android. Like Android Pie or Android 15. The same way you'd have "MacOS Leopard" built from the MacOS source code.
Android Platform: The combination of the OS, system apps, and libraries available to developers on which they can build apps of their own.
